# Prove that $P_{M^{\perp }}=P_M^{\perp }$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Result(i)
Let $H$ be a hilbert space. $M$ be a closed subspace. Let $v\in H\setminus M$ and define $d=\inf\{||v-w|| |w\in M\}$. Then there exists an unique point $w_o \in M$ such that $||v-w_o||=d.$

Let $P_M^{\perp }$ and $P_M$ are operators defined using the Orthogonal Projection on to a closed subspace $M$ given by

$P_Mv=\Big\{ 
\begin{array}{lr}
        v, & \text{if } v\in M\\
        w_0, & \text{if } v\in H\setminus M
    \end{array}$

$P_M^{\perp }v=\Big\{ 
\begin{array}{lr}
        0, & \text{if } v\in M\\
        v-w_0, & \text{if } v\in H\setminus M
    \end{array}.$

Prove that $P_{M^{\perp }}=P_M^{\perp }$.

**My attempt:-**

By definition, we can write
$P_{M^{\perp }}v=\Big\{ 
\begin{array}{lr}
        v, & \text{if } v\in M^{\perp }\\
        w^\star, & \text{if } v\in H\setminus M^{\perp }
    \end{array}$
where $w^\star$ is a unique point in $M^{\perp }$(Using Result(i)).
$P_M^{\perp }v=\Big\{ 
\begin{array}{lr}
        0, & \text{if } v\in M\\
        v-w_0, & \text{if } v\in H\setminus M
    \end{array}.$
How these two operators are same?

Comment: You don't need to define these operators by cases. E.g. $P_Mv$ is *always* equal to $w_o,$ even when $v\in M$ i.e. $d=0.$

Now $P_Mv=w_o$ and $P_{M^{\perp }}v=w^\star$ where $w_o\in M,$ $w^\star\in M^\perp,$ $\|v-w_o\|=d(v,M),$ and $\|v-w^\star\|=d(v,M^\perp),$ and what you are asking is:
$$w^\star+w_o=v?$$

Answer (score 1):

A basic theorem in Hilbert space theory says $H=M\oplus M^{\perp}$. From this it follows that  $P_{M^{\perp}}=I-P_M$. Now it is clear that $P_{M^{\perp}}=P_M^{\perp}$.